# How to touch files with different names and different date created

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, touch

I am trying to create files with different date created:

```
$ touch -t 20{11..15}01120000 file_{1..5}.txt
$ ls -al 
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2011 201201120000
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2011 201301120000
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2011 201401120000
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2011 201501120000
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2011 file_1.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2011 file_2.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2011 file_3.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2011 file_4.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2011 file_5.txt
```

As you can see all file's dates created are 2011 Jan 12 0.

How can I create files with a different year?

```
# this is what I want
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2011 file_1.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2012 file_2.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2013 file_3.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2014 file_4.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 shinokada  staff     0 Jan 12  2015 file_5.txt
```

What is the best way?

Comment: See _man touch_ . The `touch` command not only allows you to create a file, but also to give it a fake modification timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`touch` command allows you to enter one one timestamp using `-t` option.

A traditional for-loop would be better:

```
for i in {1..5}; do touch -t 201${i}01120000 file_$i.txt; done
```

Comment: Thanks. I just figure it out using while-loop as well.

Answer (score 1):

#### Shortly, but keeping *filenumbers* and *years* as separated variables

I think this is more readable, but...

**Care about timezone!**

```
filenum=1
for year in {2011..2015};do
    TZ=UTC touch -t ${year}12312345 file-$((filenum++))
  done
```

Then if you look about this, using a different *timezone*:
(Note that created date was `Dec 31, 23h45'`)

```
TZ=UTC-1 ls -ltr
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user      0 jan  1  2012 file-1
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user      0 jan  1  2013 file-2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user      0 jan  1  2014 file-3
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user      0 jan  1  2015 file-4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user      0 jan  1  2016 file-5
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, I would go with following approach with a `for` loop. Where I am providing year, number of files which needed, output file's initial value and same time value for all output files so that we can manage it in for loop.

```
cat script.bash
year=2011
numberoffiles="10"
time="01120000"
outputfileInitials="file"
nameSequence="1"

for ((i = 1 ; i <= numberoffiles ; i++ ));
do
  touch -t $year$time "${outputfileInitials}_$nameSequence.txt"
  (( nameSequence =  nameSequence + 1 ))
  (( year = year + 1 ))
done
```